# Caveats for hardcoding a single OpenID provider?

Tags: authentication, openid

We're considering a few options for single-signon between our Django web application (we'll call it Website 1) and another specific website (Website 2). Our two top priorities are:

- Ease of implementation/maintenance.
- Avoiding the complication of our login process (our audience is not technically savvy at all). In other words, I don't want them to even know what OpenID is. They know to use their credentials from Website 2, though.

There are tons of Django apps for OpenID, but we don't want our users selecting their provider (we want to force them to use their "Website 2" credentials). **This is my primary concern: Can I hardcode the provider so they are always using "Website 2" as the authority?**

Here's what my research so far seems to think would be the flow:

- User goes to the login page. We either display a button for them to click on to login, or
  we just say "We're going to redirect you to Site X for authentication" and do so after a few seconds.
- User gets redirected to Website 2. They enter their credentials and are redirected back to  us.
- The user doesn't know/care what just happened, and we have something simple to launch quickly.

Am I on the right track? Is this even possible? Do you see any caveats?

Comment: It should be possible. Website 2 must be OpenID provider though. After that You hardcode Website2 OpenID login entry point, and on login You check provider hash tag if it match with Website2, if not, then You redirect to Website2 or to some other page to handle that error.